# Adding one instance to the linked list of another instance

Tags: java, methods, linked-list

I'm a beginner Java programmer and I'm trying to add a selected object called Person in one linked list to the linked list contained in another instance class called Boat. I am able to select both objects I want, but I do not know how to add the selected Person to the linked list in the selected Boat object. I've included the Person and Boat class details to assist.

I have stripped down the code to the bare essentials to convey the question, if more of the program would assist please let me know. Any assistance is appreciated. If my question isn't clear please let me know and I'll try to rephrase the question.

Here are the two methods I'm using currently, as well as the list the boats are stored in. I've marked key areas with '// !!'

```
public class Base implements Serializable
{   private LinkedList<Boat> boats = new LinkedList<Boat>();
    private Clients clients = new Clients();


    public Base(){

    }
     // !! Here is where the boats are created
    public void setup()
    {   boats.add(new Boat(1, "Ed", 2));
        boats.add(new Boat(2, "Fred", 7));
        boats.add(new Boat(3, "Freda", 5));   }


    public void getBoat(Boat boat) { `// !! Boat has already been selected by another method`

        boat.passengers(add(getPassenger(passenger))); `// !! This is where I try to add the Person object into the linked list of the Boat object, this is the line that generates errors.`

    }

    public Person getPassenger(Person passenger) { `// !! passenger has already been selected by another method`

        return passenger; 
    }
```

And here is the boat class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Boat implements Serializable
{   
    private LinkedList<Person> passengers = new LinkedList<Person>();


    public Boat()
    {   

           }
}
```

Here is the person class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Person implements Serializable
{   private String name;
    private int id;
    private double cash = 100.00;
    private int start = 0;
    private int end = 0;
    private double charge = 0;

    public Person(String name, int id)
    {   this.name = name;
        this.id = id + 100; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method in class `Boat` to do this:

```
public class Boat implements Serializable {   
    private LinkedList<Person> passengers = new LinkedList<Person>();

    public Boat() { }

    public void addPassenger(Person p) {
        this.passengers.add(p);
    }
}
```

Then you can add passengers to a particular boat by passing a `Person` object to `addPassenger()`. For example:

```
Boat boat = new Boat();
boat.addPassenger(new Person("Bob", 1));
```

**Do not return the passenger list** in a getter method. This would break encapsulation, as other classes would be able to modify a boat's passenger list and even clean it.

There are a couple more problems in your code. For example:

```
public Person getPassenger(Person passenger) {
    return passenger; 
}
```

This method receives an object and return that same object. It does nothing else. You don't need it.

Your `getBoat()` method receives a `Boat` as argument, but inside it you try to access a `Passenger` object. Where did this passenger come from?

```
public void getBoat(Boat boat) {
    boat.passengers(add(getPassenger(passenger)));
}
```

It seems that this method should be something like:

```
public void addPassengerToBoat(Boat boat, Passenger passenger) {
    boat.addPassenger(passenger);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for you responce, but wouldn't the solution you are suggesting require me to define a new person in the boat class? I have already defined the person and just want to add that person to the list

Comment: @Mark It is just an example of how you would use `addPassenger()`. You did not create any person object in your code. Note there is no new Person(...) anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

//Since passengers in the Boat class is in private scope. You can't access like this. If you have a getter() and setter() method in Boat class for passesngers

```
public void getBoat(Boat boat) { `// !! Boat has already been selected by another method`

    boat.getPassengers().add(getPassenger(passenger))); 
 }
```

In Boat class,

```
public LinkedList<Person> getPassengers(){
 return this.passengers;
}
```

Comment: thankyou for your responce. I am encountering an error though with your solition, in boats "LinkedList<Passenger>" is returning the error "cannot find symbol - class Passenger"

Comment: thankyou for the correction, I appreciate your help. Now though the getBoat method is returning the error 'cannot find variable passenger' at this point 

boat.getPassengers().add(getPassenger(>passenger<)));

Do you have any idea how I might work around that?

Comment: That's because, you haven't defined the passenger in your class. I would suggest you to go through some java tutorials from tutorialspoint.com or mkyong. Thanks